# xtable caption cannot contain "%" character

Tags: r, caption, xtable, lyx

I have an old Lyx file that used to work, but quit working after updating R to 3.03 and updating packages.

Issue is with xtable in a longtable environment with the character `%` in the caption.

Here is a minimal example:

```
<<tabtest,results='asis'>>=
library(xtable)
table=matrix(1:12,nrow=3)
rownames(table)=c("row 1","row 2","row 3")
colnames(table)=c("c1","c2","c3","c4")
table.x=xtable(table,caption="table of %")
print(table.x,tabular.environment="longtable",floating=FALSE)
@
```

have `\usepackage{longtable}` in preamble

As presented, you get a `no legal end` error.
If you change the `%` to `percent` it works.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `%` sign using `\%`, since it implies a line-comment in TeX. So use

```
table.x=xtable(table,caption="table of \%")
```